# How to split a string with regexp without keeping capture groups?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, regex-group

I want to split text with a regular expression ***with backreference*** in `Python`.

```
rexp = re.compile(r"([`]{1,})ABC\1")
rexp.split("blahblah``ABC``blahblah")
```

I got ``` ['blahblah', '``', 'blahblah'] ``` but expected `['blahblah', 'blahblah']`.
How can I split string without keeping capture groups?

Comment: @GarbageCollector But I can't use non-capturing groups due to backreference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) documentation:

> If capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

Since you want to use a backreference you can't avoid the first capturing group, but you can make the rest of them non-capturing and post-process your split to get what you want, e.g.:

```
rexp = re.compile(r"([`]{1,})->\s*(?:\S+)\s*\|(?:.+?)<-\1")
rexp.split("blahblah``->Left|Right<-``blahblah")[0::2]  # ['blahblah', 'blahblah']
```

**UPDATE**: I just noticed that you changed your pattern in the meantime, but the principle is just the same:

```
rexp = re.compile(r"([`]{1,})ABC\1")  # also, if optimizing, equivalent to: (`+)ABC\1
rexp.split("blahblah``ABC``blahblah")[0::2]  # ['blahblah', 'blahblah']
```

Comment: Make other group non-capturing make this problem really simple, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could first replace the split pattern with a unique delimiter then split on that:

```
>>> s="blahblah``ABC``blahblah"
>>> delim="<-split->"
>>> re.split(delim, re.sub(r"([`]+)ABC\1", delim, s))
['blahblah', 'blahblah']
```

The advantage to this approach is you do not need to make an assumption on where the split pattern is in your string.

You can also then use the speedier Python split since you have converted a regex target to fixed strings:

```
>>> re.sub(r"([`]+)ABC\1", delim, s).split(delim)
['blahblah', 'blahblah']
```

---

## Update

Timing showing this is just as fast as the accepted answer:

```
import re

def f1(s):
    rexp = re.compile(r"([`]{1,})ABC\1")
    return rexp.split(s)[0::2]
    
def f2(s):
    delim="<-split->"  
    rexp1=re.compile(r"([`]+)ABC\1")  
    rexp2=re.compile(delim)
    return rexp2.split(rexp1.sub(delim, s))

def f3(s):
    delim="<-split->"  
    rexp=re.compile(r"([`]+)ABC\1")  
    return rexp.sub(delim, s).split(delim) 

if __name__=='__main__':
    import timeit    
    for case, x in (('small',1000),('med',10000),('large',1000000)):  
        s="blahblah``ABC``blahblah"*x
        print("Case {}, {:,} x, All equal: {}".format(case,x,(f1(s)==f2(s)==f3(s))))
        for f in (f1,f2,f3):
            print("   {:^10s}{:.4f} secs".format(f.__name__, timeit.timeit("f(s)", setup="from __main__ import f, s", number=10)))
```

On my older iMac, Python 3.6, prints:

```
Case small, 1,000 x, All equal: True
       f1    0.0049 secs
       f2    0.0048 secs
       f3    0.0045 secs
Case med, 10,000 x, All equal: True
       f1    0.0512 secs
       f2    0.0536 secs
       f3    0.0526 secs
Case large, 1,000,000 x, All equal: True
       f1    5.2092 secs
       f2    5.6808 secs
       f3    5.5388 secs
```

With PyPy, it is faster to do it the way I am suggesting:

```
Case small, 1,000 x, All equal: True
       f1    0.0020 secs
       f2    0.0021 secs
       f3    0.0012 secs
Case med, 10,000 x, All equal: True
       f1    0.0325 secs
       f2    0.0288 secs
       f3    0.0217 secs
Case large, 1,000,000 x, All equal: True
       f1    4.4900 secs
       f2    3.0680 secs
       f3    2.1079 secs
```

So not sure what you mean by *for very large input string, it's a terrible cost...* -- the timing show it is either the same or faster even with huge input strings.

Comment: It won't be any worse than using re.split with a similar regex. See timing... On PyPy, it is significantly *faster*